# Rendering and re-rendering routes, hooks and Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ok. I have a simple question regarding how ember handles re-rendering of routes...

## The Application

### Stuff

```
-------------------------------
Ember      : 1.8.1
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.12
Handlebars : 1.3.0
jQuery     : 1.11.2
-------------------------------
```

### Teh Codes

`router.js`

```
this.resource('categories', {path: '/categories'}, function(){
    this.resource('category', {path:'/:cid'});
});
```

I have two very simple nested templates. One named `categories` and one named `category`. They work just as you would expect. **However** my ember app has no views defined in the application, just templates.

### The Question

How can I change a simple property of the parent route's controller, say `foo: 0` from `0` to `1` when going from the parent to the child route **via `link-to` helpers** only (i.e. not reloading the route via the address bar)?

The solution needs to work when going from parent to child and **vice versa**, all from `link-to` helpers, just to be clear. I have gotten this behavior to work when going from parent to child route, just not vice-versa.

All I want to do is toggle this property of the parent route from `0` to `1`

#### UPDATE

I want to basically toggle the `foo` variable from `1` to `0` by navigating back and forth between the two routes. Imagine clicking on the `link-to` between these two routes 10 times and just seeing the property of the parent route get updated each time to the new value. **Why is this not a simple hook in the controller?** What am i missing?

### Vain Attempts Section

I have done a load of googling and tried lots of various hooks in the routes (`beforeModel`,`model`,`setupController`) and controllers. I have had no success. Would welcome a dead-easy method for tackling this if there is one. My apologies if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

categories index route

```
afterModel: function(model, transition){
    if(Ember.isEqual(this.controllerFor('application').currentRouteName, "categories.index"))
    {
       this.controllerFor('categories.index').set('foo', 0);
    }
}
```

category route

```
afterModel: function(model, transition){
    if(Ember.isEqual(this.controllerFor('application').currentRouteName, "category"))
    {
        this.controllerFor('categories.index').set('foo', 1);
    }
}
```

stick a debug on `this.controllerFor('application').currentRouteName` when on each of these pages to make sure I have the names of the routes right but that should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the `categories` route and the `category` route seem to only get evaluated one time on the initial load of the resource. After the initial load, the `setupController` hook does not seem to be getting evaluated.

Comment: yeah so maybe move the code above into the afterModel hook instead as that will get triggered everytime

Comment: i update the code to use afterModel instead, let me know if that works

Comment: This is almost working. The child route `afterModel` hook fires each time I transition from parent to child. The parent's `afterModel` hook, however, is not firing when I transition (really re-render) from child to parent (i.e. the other direction). So close. I just need a hook that will be called when moving from child __back__ to parent route. So close!

Comment: you using ember-cli? turn these on in your environment.js or put them in your app.js if your just using ember, this will help you figure out what is happening when you transition back to the parent route, it seems sometype of route hook should get triggered or transitioned to when going between routes ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
    ENV.APP.LOG_BINDINGS = true;

Comment: if not see if you can make a small js fiddle, use this as a template (http://jsfiddle.net/j1njm36w/) demonstrating it and I will debug it

Comment: Will do. Gimmie an hour or so... Thanks for your help!

Comment: actually i know the issue, you need to make a categories.index route as well as a categories route, when you transition back only the categories.index route should be triggered, do you have routes for both categories and categories.index right now?

Comment: Yeah i do have the categories index route, but its just a stub, let me see if moving the `afterModel` call there will fire the call...

Comment: That got it! I had to wrap the code in the `afterModel` hook in an `Ember.run.later(this, function() {...}, 100);` to avoid seeing the transition as 'loading' due to one of the routes having a big XHR payload. But that got it. +100. Thanks so much.